# Native Fortran type signature for "list of variable length strings"?

Tags: arrays, string, fortran

In Fortran, is there any way to declare an "array of allocatable arrays", that doesn't require wrapping the allocatable arrays into a derived type?

My main use-case would be to allow invoking a function with an array of variable-length strings, i.e. I am looking for a type signature matching the literal

```
["Hello", &
 "World.",  &
 "How are you?"]
```

### Motivation

In Fortran strings are natively represented as fixed-size character arrays, padded with blanks on the right. Arrays of strings are normally represented as arrays of (equal-length) character arrays, which I assume is in order to make them behave like a matrix of characters.

However, this also means that doing something like

```
CALL mySubroutine(["Hello","World.","How are you?"])
```

will result in a compiler error like

```
Error: Different CHARACTER lengths (5/4) in array constructor at (1)
```

A commonly suggested workaround (see e.g. [Return an array of strings of different length in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51968735/return-an-array-of-strings-of-different-length-in-fortran)) is to use an array of derived types instead, e.g.

```
TYPE string
   CHARACTER(LEN=:), ALLOCATABLE :: chars
END type string
! ...
CALL myStringSubroutine([string("Hello"), &
                         string("World."),  &
                         string("How are you?")])
```

However, since there is no standardized `string` type of this kind, I am much more frequently seeing APIs using natively supported "workarounds" such as using fixed-size character strings, and trimming them when used. In this case the invocation would look like

```
CALL myFixedSubroutine(["Hello       ", &
                        "World.      ", &
                        "How are you?"])
```

While this is no problem in principle, it can become awkward and inefficient, if one of the strings is much longer than the others. It also has implications for version control, where now changing `"... you?"` to `"... you??"` means that the padding of the other lines has to be changed, creating spurious diffs.

(In the comments, a suggestion was given that at least automates the whitespace-padding.)

Comment: There is no native list type in Fortran. There are only Fortran arrays. Arrays are not lists. There are implementations of derived list types available on the internet and often appared even here.

Comment: Note also that the array constructor `[character(135):: 'Hello', 'World.', 'How are you?']` addresses some of your concerns.

Comment: @VladimirF There may not be a native list type, but arrays can often be used in the same way, when mutable length is not required. What I'm looking for essentially comes down to using an "array of arrays" as opposed to a "rank 2 array". While the latter is obviously better for matrix performance, the first would often be more suitable in infrastructure code surrounding the calculation.

Comment: @kdb arrays of arrays were addressed here many times as well. Also arrays of pointers using wrappers which are almost the same. Just switch the pointer component with a character component. It is really the same, extremely simple. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900336/arrays-of-pointers I see you call it a workaround, but it is really the thing to go to, normally. Not sure what the question is if you know it already.

Comment: @VladimirF The wrappers are simple to write, but they make code harder to read, so I'm trying to find a solution, that doesn't need them. And with pointers, while the `TYPE(string)` would be more performant to use for such variable arguments it would become less useful in any other place, as a pointer may end up pointing at freeded memory. I am looking for ways to improve static checking capabilities, so using `POINTER` would be a step backwards.

Comment: @VladimirF It also doesn't help that parametrized types allow only parametrizing on `kind` parameters; Otherwise at least a single wrapper could be used code-base wide.

Comment: @kdb I wasn't suggesting using pointers of any sort, I was just pointing to the use of the wrapper types. So my question remains. What is your actual question now? What we normally use are the wrapper types. There is no hypothetical `TYPE(string)` if you are asking whether there is one. And it is probably impossible to implement on in any other way than with the wrapper. Unless you change the language to support different syntax. But we have to work with the language we have got. There is no string type, there is no pointer to pointer, there are no arrays of pointers and no STL.

Comment: @VladimirF The question is essentially "is there a more elegant solution than a *custom* wrapper", the intent being to avoid both the obfuscating effect of the non-standard wrapper type and the inconveniences of using rank 2 character matrices as a builtin approximation of a "list of strings".

Comment: no, thats what I have been saying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202823/discussion-between-kdb-and-vladimir-f).

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way bar the wrapper type.

A fundamental concept in the language is that elements within an array may only vary in value.  The allocation status of an object is not part of the value of that object.

(The allocation status of a component is part of the value of the object that has the component.)

A varying length string type is described in Part 2 of the Fortran standard.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "fundamental concept" part? I understand that, for the sake of performance in numerics, the language puts proper rank-N arrays front and center. I do not however understand, why this precludes the ability to create arrays of allocatables or arrays of pointers. (Other than that: Thanks for the reference `to iso_varying_string`, though I don't get why it is optional.)

Comment: How would elemental operations work?  How would sequence association work?

Comment: Sequence association would work just fine, when thinking of the array as an "array of pointers" and not as a multi-dimensional array of values. Elemental operations could be applied recursively on the innermost level of the arrays, though I can see how this makes the implementation much more complex; But it is somewhat missing the point: "Arrays of pointers" would have quite different usage scenarios compared to multi-dimensional arrays, so while elemental operations would be "nice to have", I'd hardly consider them important compared to avoiding the use of ad-hoc wrappers.